# KNeighborsClassifier with cross-validation returns perfect accuracy when k=1

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm training a KNN classifier using [scikit-learn's KNeighborsClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) with cross validation:

```
k=1
param_space = {'n_neighbors': [k]}
model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k, metric='euclidean')
search = GridSearchCV(model, param_space, cv=cv, verbose=10, n_jobs=8)
search.fit(X_df, y_df)
preds = search.best_estimator_.predict(X_df)
```

when `k=1` and with any cv value (lets say `cv=4`), I'm getting perfect score

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_df, preds).ravel()
f1 = tp / (tp + 0.5 * (fp + fn))
# f1 is perfect 1
```

It is important to say that I use this method on multiple datasets, and every time `k=1` the score is a perfect 1. I tried doing it on random data and still got `f1=1`.

Is there any known bug with `KNeighborsClassifier` when `k=1`? Maybe I'm missing something else?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predictions are from the `best_estimator_`, which is a copy of the estimator with the optimal hyperparameters (according to the cross-validation scores) *refitted to the entire training set*.  So the confusion matrix you generate is really a training score, and for 1-neighbors that's trivially perfect (the nearest neighbor of a point is itself).